# Details method doesn't take parameter, mvc

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I'm using MVC, c# and one of the methods of the code, doesn't take the id. I don't know why. Can you help me, please?:D

Here is my method from controller

```
 public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {

        AngajatRepository y = new AngajatRepository(conn);
        AngajatModel obAngajat = y.DetaliiAngajat(id);
        return View(obAngajat);
    }
```

And this is my repository

```
 public AngajatModel DetaliiAngajat(int? id)
    {

        var obAngajat = new AngajatModel();
        oracleConnection.Open();
        string oString = "select angajat.marca, angajat.nume_ang, angajat.prenume_ang, angajat.data_nastere, angajat.data_ang, angajat.sex, angajat.cnp, angajat.salariu, departament.denum_dep, studii.tip_stud  from angajat inner join departament on angajat.departament_id_departam=departament.id_departam inner join studii on angajat.studii_id_stud=studii.id_stud and marca=:marca";
        using (var cmdg = new OracleCommand(oString, oracleConnection))
        {
            cmdg.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":marca", id));
            using (OracleDataReader rd = cmdg.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rd.Read())
                {

                    obAngajat.Marca = Convert.ToInt32(rd["marca"]);
                    obAngajat.NumeAngajat = Convert.ToString(rd["nume_ang"]);
                    obAngajat.PrenumeAngajat = Convert.ToString(rd["prenume_ang"]);
                    obAngajat.DataNastere = Convert.ToDateTime(rd["data_nastere"]);
                    obAngajat.DataAngajarii = Convert.ToDateTime(rd["data_ang"]);
                    obAngajat.Sex = Convert.ToString(rd["sex"]);
                    obAngajat.CNP = Convert.ToString(rd["cnp"]);
                    obAngajat.Salariu = Convert.ToDouble(rd["salariu"]);
                    obAngajat.Departament = Convert.ToString(rd["denum_dep"]);
                    obAngajat.Studii = Convert.ToString(rd["tip_stud"]);
                }
                oracleConnection.Close();
            }
        }

        return (obAngajat);
    }
```

P.S. I have no error or exception. It just don't take my id from controller.

Comment: Have you debugged this?

Comment: Please read [ask] and explain what you mean by "take the ID". Do you mean you visit `/Foo/Details/42`, and `id` is `null` when you put a breakpoint in the `Details()` method?

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad ask. Yes...this is what i mean. I visit http://localhost:*****/Angajat/Details/1111 and the id is null.

Comment: And yes... I debugged this but I don't find to much...just my id remain null.

Comment: can u share controller name and routing configuration

Comment: localhost:*****/Angajat/Details/"id"